# How to set up paypal subscription payment system

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I need to set up a paypal monthly subscription system for a membership site in PHP.

I have set up the paypal PHP SDK to make api call and I am able to create billing plans, creating agreements and executing them for the users, by following the paypal docs. 
I am following this doc :- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/integrate-steps/

What i now have is, whenever a user comes I create a new plan, a new agreement and execute that agreement.

I need 3 plans, with different cost. I want to know should I first create the plans and store their IDs to create agreements with them OR I have to create a new plan each time a new user comes.

Comment: "Plans" are there to reuse - not create a new one for each user (unless they have something different in their plan - you didn't state if they require something unique each time.... - but, if they do, then of course, they would need a new plan).

Comment: @CFPSupport Sorry I forgot to mention, but they are unique. So you answered my question. I will reuse the same plan. Thanks a lot!